# How do I remove a tag from enclosing tag

Tags: parsing, jsoup

```
 <td align="center" nowrap=""><img border="0" src="bus0.gif" /><font style="color:darkblue;">030-

 FP</font><br />將到站</td>
```

For the above HTML, I'd like to remove the img and font tags as well as font tag's enclosed text using JSoup.  How should I go about doing that?

Thanks!

Edit:  I would like to remove the img and font tags, so the output would be

```
 <td align="center" nowrap="">將到站</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Assuming that you have a Document variable called doc
String img = doc.select("img").attr("src");
String font = doc.select("font").text();
```

And take a closer look at the API. It takes about 10 mins to find this out.

Comment: Thanks! but I wanted to remove the elements, not extract the attribute values.

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of hard to understand. Tell me what's the EXACT output you'd like to get, plz. (Edit your question)

Comment: @IgorBrusamolinLoboSantos Heh, he edited the question, but never told you.